# how to find word in sentence, use string or another at php

Tags: php, string

find word position in sentence, **example** : **Sentence** : i like manggo *juice* and apple *juice*. **find word** : ***juice***  and the answer is **the word "juice" found at position 4 and 7**

before, i used strpos, but the answer is -> the word "juice" found at **14** and **30**. i wanna like this -> the word "juice" found at 4 and 7. please help.. really really help me.. because, i'm newbie in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `explode` function to split your input according to the spaces. Loop through the array and then print the index number + 1 where the string `juice` is found.

```
$string = "i like manggo juice and apple juice";
$parts = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($parts as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === "juice")
    {
        echo ($key + 1)."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Avinash,

how to make the position is found else not found.
like this
the word is found in sentence at position 2 5 or the word is not found in sentence.